# No content types showing under 'Add content'

Tags: nodes

When I click "Add content," I get the following message:

> You have not created any content types yet. Go to the content type creation page to add a new content type.

However, under content types it lists all my content types (page, article, blog, etc). What could be causing this sort of miscommunication? The only change I made recently was moving the "Add content" link from one menu to another, but that shouldn't have affected the actual behaviour of node/add. (I did it using the admin interface as well; I didn't do any PHP editing of any sort.)

This is my recent log messages since the last content I added (edited out repeats and page not found errors):

```
cron    12/29/2011 - 13:02  Cron run completed. Anonymous (not verified)
php 12/29/2011 - 10:42  Notice: Undefined index: path in menu_edit_item...  admin
php 12/29/2011 - 10:42  Notice: Undefined index: path in menu_edit_item...  admin
user    12/29/2011 - 10:35  Session opened for admin.   admin
cron    12/29/2011 - 10:02  Cron run completed. Anonymous (not verified)
cron    12/29/2011 - 01:20  Cron run completed. Anonymous (not verified)
content 12/29/2011 - 00:37  page: updated Mentoring Program.    admin
content 12/29/2011 - 00:34  page: added Mentoring Program.  admin
```

Only change to any files was a small change to pages.tpl.php regarding rendering of page titles; and I haven't installed any modules since it last worked.

Comment: You're going to have to answer a few questions and do some debugging: 1. Was it showing content types before?  2. Have you installed any modules since this started happening?  3. Have you uploaded custom files or edited any files?

Comment: I don't remember exactly when it started, but I don't think anything has changed, or any modules installed. Do you know if there's a simple way of seeing when the last time content was added was just so I can be sure?

Comment: `www.mysite.com/?q=admin/reports/dblog`  That will give you the full log of any changes to your site. If I'm not mistaken, this should be enabled.

Comment: good to know! I edited the q with some additional details abt updates and the log...

Comment: i found this http://drupal.org/node/997444  one of the dumbest bugs I've seen heh. Put things back and still not working..

Comment: Have you removed any shortcuts/links to the Add Content page? Maybe from the admin panel?

Comment: Yeah.. I had to re-add the add-content link to the administration menu and re-check all the submenu items, then set it to display:none and add the 'add content' link to the user menu again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found this :
http://drupal.org/node/997444
it seems like it's a very strange behaviour.

Basically I guess Drupal looks at that specific main menu to see what types of content can be created by users, so if even if you move all the options to a different menu none will be available.

I had to re-add the add-content link to the administration menu and re-check all the submenu items, then set it to `display:none;` and add the '***Add content***' link to the user menu again.

Answer (score 1):

Shot in the dark...permissions? I've hunted around for hours for a bug only to realise that I didn't actually have the permissions to perform the task in question.