# No content type problem

Tags: nodes

When I go to node/add. I see the message showing there is no content type:
[image]
But, when I go to admin/structure/types. I see three content types I have :
[image]

What could that be the problem ?
I'm using Drupal 7.14.

Comment: what user are you logged in as?

Comment: I logged in as administrator.

Comment: Is this a new Drupal installation ?

Comment: It was ok with fresh installation and it was also ok after I have added a new content type. I could not catch when it happened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a fix [here](http://drupal.org/node/997444#comment-3823720) with the help of Mohini.

I needed only "Add Vehicle" link in the navigation menu. Thus, I added it with the path "node/add/vehicle". Then I disabled "Add content" and all of its sub-links (Article, Basic page and Vehicle).

Now, when I enabled the Vehicle sub-link (I didn't enable the "Add content" back, and I kept the "Add Vehicle" menu I created earlier), I was redirected to node/add/vehicle from node/add. This is exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 2):

Try these.

1) You may have changed the Navigation block settings:(Administration -> Structure -> Blocks -> 'Navigation'). Configure the 'Navigation' block under 'Content types'.

2) Configure :structure>menus>navigation>listlinks (if you are using Bartik theme).

Reference: http://drupal.org/node/1166416, http://drupal.org/node/1094238

Comment: The problem is not "New Content Type Not Showing Up in Add Content", but all content types are not showing up in the node/add page.

Comment: check the references which i have mentioned. It covers both New content and your area of interest All content types not showing up.

Comment: If you didn't find in those links check these:http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/18534/no-content-types-showing-under-add-content, http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/18534/no-content-types-showing-under-add-content