# New custom content type not showing up in 'Create content' menu

Tags: routes, nodes

I have created some new content types but they automatically don't show up in the 'Create content' menu - what do I have to do to get them there. I am currently logged in as user 1 so it shouldn't be a permissions issue.

Comment: Cleared caches?

Comment: yes cache cleared. many... many times.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are facing the same problem I've experienced. Probably you disabled the navigation menu link "Add Content" and its respective sub-menu items. Then, they won't show up at the path **node/add**.

See this Q/A: [No content type problem](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/38149/no-content-type-problem)

Answer (score -1):

Try clearing your cache on Drupal.