# How to restore private file structure after major version update?

Tags: files

After a Drupal 6 to 7 update we are unable to use private image download, symptom is we cannot access private files via system/files, while public files can be loaded.

Trying to download private file results in a 404 -- Not found error, sent from the web-server directly, not drupal. After some changes to the configuration this results instead in a Drupal Error page. The server log says

`File does not exist: /home/licebase/drupal/system/files/genefinding_diagram_1_2.png, referer: https://myhost/node/761470/edit?render=overlay`

The system file exists and has the correct permissions.

**Centos 6 on virtualization host, PHP 5.3.3, Postgres 8.4 on dedicated DB server, Apache 2.2.15 (centos) + a lot of active modules + fields+cck**

Comment: There never has been a good upgrade path till D8. Can you give a better description of your setup?

Comment: This is an update from a running d6 instance including tripal (see: http://tripal.info that should have no relevance here). Running on a cloned vm under centos, using postgres 8.4 db host, php5.3.3, apache, drush 6.7, using CCK, views and a bunch of other models. Core update was done following the standard update procedure. Please let me know, if you need any specific information.

Comment: Please be aware that bug reports are off topic here.

Comment: Well, I am not even sure it is a bug, I am in the process of finding out, it might still be a misconfiguration. Is there any relevant input you could give me on topic? I appreciate any constructive hint. Also, who says they are off topic? Would also the disparate question of how to debug a real error  be off topic here? Then this site wouldn't be very useful overall.

Comment: @Michael It's Q+A, so ask a specific, objectively answerable question, get a specific, objective answer. That's the only thing this site is useful for (intentionally so). General hints on where to start, how to debug a site, and other broadly natured requests don't fit the format very well so don't be too surprised if people don't engage here. There are forums out there if you need a back-and-forth/support style request. BTW it's the [help] that lists bug reports/workarounds as off-topic - discussions about such things happen in the module issue queue, not here, for a variety of reasons

Comment: I hope to convince you that my question is specific and objectively answerable in case anyone has observed something similar, further I hope we convinced you that we already have tried a lot. From my own experience as administrator of a QA site I know that this format is not good for back-and forth or debugging. However, you will also find that we haven't had any significant input on any our questions so far except our own findings to a problem (where there has been no other sufficient solutions out there). So there is not much back-and forth to complain about.

Comment: @Michael I do appreciate that, I hope by the same token you appreciate that we can't, and don't, concern ourselves with users' deadlines/other pressures - we're only interested in the **quality** of the content that's provided, and its suitability to our mission. That's why the experts keep coming back here, because we insist questions follow a tried and tested format. It's great that you're contributing elsewhere in the ecosystem, but that wouldn't entitle you to ask off-topic questions (nor anyone else, the rules are the same for everyone) _here_. The effort you've put in to asking the...

Comment: ...question, and solving the problem yourself, is great, keep that up! But you have to admit that you've thrown a "what might be wrong?" question out there, and are hoping to incrementally update your question based on responses,eventually working your way to the root cause of the problem. I'm just saying Q+A doesn't support that, so I wouldn't personally be surprised if it gets closed (there are 2 "Too broad" close votes on it already), or if people give up engaging after a couple of increments. This site was never intended for the sort of engagement and support I think you'll need here

Comment: Please feel free to close the question then, hope you are not deleting it. Comparing it to other questions here, I would think that it is of rather high quality though (the analysis backing it I mean). If not feel free to propose any improvement. I am sure other users have similar problems and once we solve this, we will put the answer here and clean up the question. Also, if you want to or know anyone who could take this on as a paid task, please contact me at admin@licebase.org

Comment: You misunderstand me - I'm just trying to help you understand why this might end up closed, I'm not commenting on its quality, I'm not closing it myself (or deleting it), I'm just responding to your initial confusion about bug reports being off topic, and providing a bit of commentary around how the site works at the same time. I _wish_ that every question here was as detailed and well thought out as yours, kudos for that, but I've seen it all before dozens of times. When there could be multiple, equally valid, answers to a question, it's difficult to see it staying in Q+A. Can't chat, no time

Comment: Not sure why on hold now, as I predicted the question has a definite answer, given by us. Honestly, this QA is not really working out for us.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: We have a workaround, I hope this question can serve as a good practice guide of good to debug complex software like Drupal showing unexplainable errors or WSOD. Wish we had followed our own advice to not waste time on our futile attempts time.

tl;dr It was the core module **Database logging 7.42    Logs and records system events to the database.** which is interfering with private files in our specific setting. We disabled most modules including core, and brought them back one-by one. Database logging is reproducibly inducing the error on activation.

1. Don't panic and make a debugging plan, listing options of what could be checked, and then stick to it until everything has been checked. If out of options, try to shake things up
2. Compare your system to a vanilla system and note down what is does differently
3. Modules might interfere with each other in unexpected ways or with your specific configuration. That doesn't mean there is a bug in any of those modules. Boil down your system to the least complex configuration possible, remove any unneeded entry in your configuration file, disable any module that can be disabled including core modules, suspect everyone.
4. Check if error still present, if not re-enable all modules one-by-one, and note down which configuration change causes the error. Otherwise, start debugging going to 1.

### Cheers

Comment: Hold your horses, dude. Have you really tried everything? Nope, follow your plan and everything will work out ....